# Combination of text file not generate after running cmd from VBA EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file

I tried to run Command in CMD from excel VBA to combine file to the only single file but its not wrok. And that `command work properly when I run directly in folder`

Excel VBA 2013

```
Sub CombineFiles()
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

    wsh.Run "D:\Excel\FT\cmd.bat"
End Sub
```

MY Code Inside CMD

```
copy *.txt combined.txt
```

I expect to get the combination of all text file into single file named `Combined.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your .bat file, you need to change the directory to point to the folder location of the .txt files:

```
d:
cd\Excel\FT
copy *.txt combined.txt
PAUSE
```

or

```
copy D:\Excel\FT\*.txt D:\Excel\FT\combined.txt
PAUSE
```

I have added a pause so you can see the result of the running bat file, if you wish you can remove the `pause` command.

Comment: Great, It works now. I found the reason is directory I set in CMD not proper.

Comment: Actually, neither is needed, all that was required was to reference the scripts own directory. So either add a line at the top of the script similar to :`@CD /D "%~dp0"` or use it in your `Copy` command: `@Copy /Y "%~dp0*.txt" "%~dp0combined.txt"`. Using this syntax helps to keep things more dynamic instead of hardcoding paths.